# Python - Read multiple excel files and print data in a folder

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I can read multiple excel files in a folder by using **os**:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import math

folder = r'C:\Users\Denny\Desktop\Work\test_read'
files = os.listdir(folder)

for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(folder,file), header = None, skiprows=[0,1])

files
```

And it indeed shows three excel files:

```
Out[33] ['test_3d.xlsx', 'test_3d1.xlsx', 'test_3d2.xlsx']
```

But if I want to read the data in, for example, **test_3d.xlsx**, I used

```
test_3d.xlsx
```

or

```
print(text_3d)
```

I got

```
NameError: name 'test_3d' is not defined
```

I can only get the last one, i.e., **test_3d2**, by

```
print(df)
```

[image]

My question is how to get the data of the other two .xlsx files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrote the first two dataframes as you used the same name.

Instead save them in a dictionary:

```
dfs ={}
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        dfs[file[:-5]] = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(folder,file), header = None, skiprows=[0,1])
```

You can then access them by name:

```
dfs['test_3d']
```

Comment: Do we have to use [:-5] no matter how many excel files we want to read?   I mean if using [:-6]. Thanks!

Comment: This is just to remove the ".xlsx'", this is the simplest but there are other methods to remove extensions from strings.